# Characterising wavelet frames using Fourier transform

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, wavelets

As usual, for $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$
$$
D_j(f)(x) = 2^{j/2} f(2^jx), T_k(f)(x) = f(x-k)
$$

and let $\{D_j T_k \varphi\}$ be a system of wavelets on $\mathbb R.$

A simple result is that, $T_k \varphi$ is an orthonormal collection of translates if and only if
$$
\sum_n |\hat \varphi(\gamma+n)|^2 = 1
$$
for almost every $\gamma\in \mathbb R.$ And if we have the weaker condition
$$
0<C_1\leq\sum_n |\hat \varphi(\gamma+n)|^2 \leq C_2
$$
then there exists a constant $C_3$ such that

$$
\sum_{n} |\langle f,T_k\varphi \rangle|^2 \leq C_3 \|f\|_{L^2}^2.
$$

Now, my question is that, is it possible to generalise this in such a way so that the condition: for each $f\in L^2$
$$
0<C_1\|f\|_{L^2}^2\leq \sum_{j,k} |\langle f, D_j T_k\varphi \rangle|^2\leq C_2 \|f\|_{L^2}^2
$$

is equivalent to a condition stated in terms of $\hat\varphi$?